# How to change Tab background in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbarsherlock for the tab view and I want to change the background image of the tab.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to set a drawable as background for the actionbar tabs.

But is is certainly possible to change the actionbar colors. You can use the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to generate a style that contains all the colors you like.

The generator should create a zip with all the needed style and drawable files for your actionbar. You know can reference this styles in application theme or the themes for the activities that should use the style.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried,

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_head));
```

For more details, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12444781/1626878)
and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11184999/1626878)

**Edit-**
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12225575/1626878), if it helps.

Comment: yes, it only changes the background of the actionbar not tabs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use setIcon():

```
tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_home_unselect);
```

Comment: when you use that icon shows but not as a background.fo instance if you add a text on tab,it shows up next to drawable not on it

Comment: That's correct.  It would be OK as it is, but it also adds padding on the left and right of the icon so you can still see the tab background.